# Sending Multiple Data to HTML Component From Page Code

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, velo

I have my Page Code sending data to a HTML component which is used to process paypal payments.

On my page I have 2 values I need to send
I am doing this on my page code:

```
let obj = {amount: amount, currency: currency};
await $w("#html1").postMessage(obj);
```

And on my HTML Component I have this currently

```
let AMOUNT = 0;
        window.onmessage = (event) => {
            if (event.data > 0) {
            AMOUNT = event.data;
            }
        }
```

which leads to defining the Amount & Currency as below:

```
return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: `${AMOUNT}`, currency: `${CURRENCY}` }
                            }
                        ]
```

The problem is its not working and I cannot figure out how to separate the values for AMOUNT & CURRENCY separately from event.data.

I tried this but to no avail

```
let AMOUNT = 0;
let CURRENCY = 0;
        window.onmessage = (event) => {
            if (event.data > 0) {
            AMOUNT = event.data(amount);
            CURRENCY = event.data(currency);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get `event.data` in the HTML Component, you're getting the entire object you sent. So, to break up that object, just use dot notation.

```
window.onmessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data) {
    AMOUNT = event.data.amount;
    CURRENCY = event.data.currency;
  }
}
```

You can probably also simplify the `payment.create` call using this line instead.

```
amount: { total: AMOUNT, currency: CURRENCY }
```